# Finding duplicate values in a col and copying values from adjacent cell with specific characters to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel spreadsheet with the following data

Data

[image]

and I am trying to change it into this format

Desired output

[image]

I tried the following

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A18,$A:$A,0)),0)
```

but it only returns the first product name that match the code

Data 2

[image]

I added a search to the previous but that did not work for green.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("green",IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0)),0))),IFERROR(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH($A2,$A:$A,0)),0),"")
```

Could someone please help?

Comment: Are there always two items per code?

Comment: The code can have two or more items.

Answer (score 0):

In one go:

[image]

Formula in `D2`:

```
=LET(X,A2:A7,IFERROR(UNIQUE(HSTACK(A2:A7,MAKEARRAY(ROWS(X),MAX(COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7)),LAMBDA(r,c,INDEX(FILTER(B2:B7,X=INDEX(X,r)),c))))),""))
```

Probably overthinking this...

Comment: Thank you, but the formula does not work for me for some reason. The issue seems to be with the LAMBDA (LAMBDA(r,c,)function in the formula.